# Counting Precedant Entries of a column and creating a new varaible of these counts

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame and I want to count the number of consecutive entries of one column and record the counts in a separate variable. Here is an example:

```
ID    Class    
1      A        
1      A        
2      A        
1      B        
1      B        
1      B        
2      B        
1      C        
1      C        
2      A        
2      A        
2      A
```

I want in each group ID to count the number of consecutive classes, so the output would look like this:

```
ID    Class   Counts
1      A       0
1      A       1
2      A       0
1      B       0
1      B       1
1      B       2
2      B       0
1      C       0
1      C       1
2      A       0
2      A       1
2      A       2
```

I am not looking the frequency of occurrence of a specific entries like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python), rather the  consecutive occurrences of an entry on the ID level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by `Series` which is create by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of shifted concanecate values by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
#use separator which is not in data like _ or ¥
s = df['ID'].astype(str) + '¥' + df['Class']
df['Counts'] = df.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
print (df)
    ID Class  Counts
0    1     A       0
1    1     A       1
2    2     A       0
3    1     B       0
4    1     B       1
5    1     B       2
6    2     B       0
7    1     C       0
8    1     C       1
9    2     A       0
10   2     A       1
11   2     A       2
```

Another solution with [`ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) (`pandas 0.20.2+`):

```
s = df.groupby(['ID','Class']).ngroup()
df['Counts'] = df.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
print (df)
    ID Class  Counts
0    1     A       0
1    1     A       1
2    2     A       0
3    1     B       0
4    1     B       1
5    1     B       2
6    2     B       0
7    1     C       0
8    1     C       1
9    2     A       0
10   2     A       1
11   2     A       2
```